# Как выполнять задание типа "Каким способом образовано это слово?"

Tags: словообразование

Если у меня задание определить способ образования слова, то мне нужно выполнить его исходя из непроизводного слова в словообразовательной цепочке, в которую входит данное слово, или исходя из предыдущего звена в этой словообразовательной цепочке? Например, вот цепочка: соль → солить → пересолить → пересаливать → пересаливание.  Если мне нужно определить способ образования слова *пересаливание*, то я должен исходить из слова *соль* или из слова *пересаливать*?

Comment: @БотБотович, кавычки, по-моему, излишни.

Comment: Да, я осознал это уже после отправки правки. Их можно поставить, однако это не необходимо.

Comment: Да, можно, если дословно цитируешь. Но убрал, надеюсь, Вы не против. И, кстати, во всех онлайн-словарях, что я видел, за курсивным или жирным словом следует знак препинания с таким же выделением, поэтому я оставляю хотя бы курсив (иногда и жирный тоже). Просто чтоб не удивляло, объясняю. Вот только если цитирую и вместо кавычек использую курсив и/или жирный, тогда, если у меня вопросительное предложение в самой фразе, а не цитате, делаю вопрос без выделения, если можно ошибочно прочитать цитату вопросительно.

Answer (score 1):

**План словообразовательного разбора**

1. Поставить слово в начальную форму.
2. Указать основу слова и определить, является ли оно производным.
3. Для производного слова подобрать словообразовательную пару (**слово, от которого непосредственно образовано разбираемое слово)**.
4. Указать основу в производящем слове.
5. Указать словообразовательные приставки, суффиксы, постфиксы (если они есть).
6. Указать способ образования слова.

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/658-215_morfemnyi_i_slovoobrazovatelnyi_razbor_slova.

**Пример разбора**

1. Начальная форма – пересаливание.
2. Основа слова – пере-сал-ива-ни- . Основа производная.

**3–4. Пере-сал-ива-ть ← пере-сал-ива-ни-е**

5. -ни – словообразовательный суффикс.
6. Суффиксальный способ.

**Приложение**

**Почему вы выделяем суффикс ИВА, а не суффикс ВА.**

Впрочем, как я вижу, это никому не интересно, так что материал удален.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, определение способа образования слова подразумевает нахождение ближайшего родственного слова вверх по словообразовательной цепочке и указание морфем, использованных при данном процессе. Таким образом, задание, примером которого является Ваше слово “пересаливание”, необходимо выполнить следующим образом:

1. *Пересаливание* — процесс добавления в определённый продукт избыточного количества какой-либо соли. Как мы знаем, существительные **со значением отвлечённого действия** всегда образуются от соответствующего глагола определённого вида. Например, слово “создание” может быть образовано либо от глагола “создать” (совершенный вид глагола; существительное является синонимом к слову “существо”), либо от глагола “создавать” (несовершенный вид глагола; существительное обозначает процесс создания чего-либо), и, соответственно, при выполнении задания необходимо указать для каждого существительного свой собственный глагол-родитель. В нашем же случае слово “пересаливание” имеет **только значение отвлечённого действия** и, следовательно, образовано только от глагола “пересаливать”.
2. Что касается словообразовательной цепочки (если в её создании ещё есть смысл), она имеет следующий вид:

**Соль** (непр.) → сол**и**ть (гл. суфф. -и) → **пере**солить(прист. -пере) → перес*а*ли**ва**ть (изменение корн. гласной для образования несов. вида, суфф. -ва) → пересалива**ни**е (суффикс -ни, появление окончания -е)

**Примечания**:

1) Для образования несовершенного вида глагола “солить” потребовалось изменить корневую гласную с “о” на “а”;

2) В слове “пересаливать” суффикс -ва, а не -ива, что объясняется суффиксом -и у слова-родителя “пересолить”.

Comment: А как же мнение А. Тихонова? У него: пересолить — пере/сал/ива/ть (пересол — без суффикса "и"). См.: https://books.google.ee/books?id=2Zf1AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA445&lpg=PA445&dq=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=sbiGl4jM-5&sig=ACfU3U3-CgT7EPzrfUefcNKyyRb-QwT0Yg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDwsn77-biAhWGxMQBHcWaDQEQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Очень странно, Римма. Я читал, что при выборе суффиксов -*ва и -ва следует обращать внимание именно на глагол совершенного вида. Даже не знаю, почему у Тихонова суффикс -ива.

Comment: Спасибо за кавычки★

Comment: Не за что) А что думаете по поводу моего комментария?

Comment: Да, Вы всё верно делаете, я считаю. Вот только, насколько я знаю, на форуме нет возможности выделять знаки препинания, если они стоят сразу после “звёздочки”.

Comment: А что за форум?

Comment: Ну Вы даёте... Stack exchange обиделся

Comment: Я правда не знаю! Или если знаю, то как-то по-другому это называю. Просветите, пожалуйста!

Comment: Ну вот! Так и не выяснил, что такое форум. :( Видимо, у нас разная терминология в голове.